# userNotificationCenter didReceive response contains empty notification (watchOS)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, watchkit

I am trying to retrieve the original notification content from [userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) in watchOS. I have managed to get the callback firing when sending a push notification from APNS, but unfortunately, the `response` object contains an empty `notification`:

`<UNNotificationResponse: 0x600003bc0b40; actionIdentifier: start, notification: (null)>`

I am using the example from [Listing 1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions) from Apple's documentation.

**UPDATE 10/19/20**

I have created a sample project [SampleNotification](https://github.com/jyviko/SampleNotification) to reproduce the issue (see README.md on how to reproduce). I have noticed that the callback returns an empty notification only when the user presses the `UNNotificationAction`. Moreover, I confirmed that this pattern is **not** observed in iOS.

It appears that the same notification when received in `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` is not empty!

I'd appreciate any feedback

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No, and I am surprised that nobody has had the same problem. I have noticed though that the problem persists if you have a `options: [.foreground]` in `UNNotificationAction`. In all other cases, the notification object is populated.

Comment: i am also experiencing the same problem i don't know why but  its working fine in xcode 11 and after i update this to 12 i am facing this issue. i don't know, may be the updatation in  xcode causing this problem

Comment: @jiko did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with watchOS 7.1 and ios 14.1. I contacted the Apple technical support team. This is the reply I got from them

> "Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that you are experiencing a known issue for which there is no known workaround at this time."

Comment: Love the  "there is no known workaround at this time"!

Comment: i am still getting this same issue please do something.......